# Spring obfuscation

Tags: java, spring

I've been looking for any solutions to obfuscate a project which uses Spring MVC framework, but I didn't find anything.

When I obfuscate a project with ProGuard, for example, I have something like this:

Before the obfuscation:

Class A:

```
class A {
MyObject obj1;

//Constructors
//getters & setters
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="objectOne" class="com.myproject.MyClass" />
<!-- Injection -->
<bean id="A" class="com.myproject.controller.A">
  <property name="obj1" ref="objectOne" />
</bean>
```

After the Obfuscation:

```
class A {
  Z a = new Z();

 //Constructors
 //Getters & Setters
}
```

But the ApplicationContext remains the same...

Is there any way to obfuscate the classes and the applicationContext?

Comment: Why would you need to obfuscate a web application? It runs on your own servers anyway.

Comment: It isn't a web application... It is a desktop application which uses spring framework.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara, please, can you post here a link that shows how to Obsfuctate a Spring MVC project? I haven't found any helpfull yet and I can see that you already found the way to do that.

Comment: @LuisTeijon, I'm really sorry, but I didn't find anything about it and Jin Kim's answer was the "end of line" for me. Besides, I'm not currently working on that project anymore, so I stopped looking for. Anyway, I really hope you can find something about it. Nowadays I'd probably find some pattern name to put on my classes. I remember that, back in time, we've decided to leave the portability behind and change our .jar file into a .exe file, because our clients were Windows Users. This way, portability wasn't a problem at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obfuscation doesn't work when reflection is involved since it won't know which files contain references to the original class name.

Comment: Got it, @JinKim... so, try to obfuscate will be a complete waste of time?

Comment: It's not a complete waste of time, as long as you can live with not obfuscating code that needs to be referenced through reflection. Whether or not that's acceptable is a different story.